# Sharepoint Content of file in library linked in list search problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, document-library, search

I have a list with a column with links to word-documents in a library on the same site.

When I search something in the content of the files within the list, I get no results.

When I do the same search in the library itself, I get the right results.

What could be the problem? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design and expected behavior in SharePoint sites.

You cannot search the content of files in SharePoint list just because you have links to the files in the list.

You have to search for file content either in the same document library itself or at site level (from home page or other site pages) to get the results.

**Search from library**:

[image]

**Search from home page**:

[image]

**Search from list**:

When you try to search from SharePoint default list view pages, it will show searches only from that particular list:

[image]

Comment: Txs a lot. I thought that there was somehow a way to do this anyway...

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot.

Comment: Please [mark this as an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.

Comment: Agree with Ganesh Sanap. You could not search contents of files in the list only contains files links.